# How to recover when server socket exits from listening

Tags: java, sockets

In this application I have a server socket which waits for clients to connect. My problem is when there is a runtime exception while listening socket exit from listening. So clients cannot connect to the system. So I need to restart the server. Until that clients cannot connect. Following I have shown part of my code.

```
private Socket socket;
private SSLServerSocket ssocket; 
private int port=6666;

//here I have code need to create a serversocket

while (listen) {
    //wait for client to connect//  
    try{
        socket = ssocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }      
}
```

Can any one suggest me a way to relisten to the same port without restarting the server if an exception occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your while loop into yet another while loop that never exits and tries to reconnect.

```
private Socket socket;
private SSLServerSocket ssocket; 
private int port=6666;

while(true) {
    // Here I have code needed to create a ServerSocket
    try {
        connectToServerSocket();
    }  catch (IOException) {
        // log the exception
        continue;
    }


    while (listen) {
        // wait for client to connect
        try{
            socket = ssocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to close and reopen the ServerSocket and then begin accepting connections

Comment: How can i know when a unchecked exception is occured. If it is checked exception I can catch it and reopen the socket.

Comment: @ganuke `try { ... } catch(Throwable t) { }` but you should make sure you know all the throwables you may catch there.

Comment: @khachik can throwabel catch all unchecked exceptions and errors,etc

Comment: @ganuke Yes, it catches all throwables - `Error` and `Exception`. But it is not a good habit to catch everything.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) doesn't mention what may cause `IOException` on accept. It seems that you can continue accepting incoming connections after `IOException` on `accept`. `man 2 accept` describes the following possible errors (bolds are mine):

```
 [EBADF]            socket is not a valid file descriptor. - **doesn't make sence**
 [ECONNABORTED]     The connection to socket has been aborted. - **recoverable**
 [EFAULT]           The address parameter is not in a writable part of the user
                    address space. - **doesn't make sence**
 [EINTR]            The accept() system call was terminated by a signal. **not I/O**
 [EINVAL]           socket is unwilling to accept connections. **doesn't make sence**
 [EMFILE]           The per-process descriptor table is full. **??? Don't know**
 [ENFILE]           The system file table is full. **recoverable**
 [ENOMEM]           Insufficient memory was available to complete the operation. 
                    **I'm not sure this will cause I/O**
```

Another option is to close the server socket on `IOExceptions` and create it again. This allows to listen the same port again without restarting the server, but there will be a time gap when clients cannot connect.

Comment: EFAULT doesn't make sense *in Java.* EINVAL means it's not a listening socket, which doesn't happen in Java. EMFILE and ENFILE are both recoverable after some fd's are closed. ENOMEM is recoverable if memory becomes available. EINTR is handled by Java. The others are not recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

No worries. I've ended with this:

```
// maximum number of restarts for socket server
private final AtomicLong reconnectCounter = new AtomicLong(MAX_RECONNECT);

public void run() {     
    boolean reconnect = false;      
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = null; 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();      
    try {           

        // handle pretty rare situation when exit flag was already set
        if (t.isInterrupted()) {
            Thread.interrupted();   
            logger.error("Monitor thread was started with interrupted status set");
            return;
        }       

        ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();           
        final InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(BIND_IP), conf.monitoringPort);
        serverSocket = ssc.socket(); 
        serverSocket.bind(isa);
        ssc.configureBlocking(false); // active polling mode                        
        while (!t.isInterrupted()) {
            boolean succ = false;
            SocketChannel chan = null;
            Socket s = null;
            try {       
                chan = null;
                s = null;
                chan = ssc.accept();                    
                if (chan != null) {                     
                    s = chan.socket();
                    logger.error("Accepting message from @" + (s != null ? s.getRemoteSocketAddress() : "null"));
                    final long ts = createTimestamp();
                    MonitorTask task = new MonitorTask(s, ts, MonitorPoolService.this, monitorEmailService);
                    ExecutorService exec = this.taskExecutor;
                    if (exec != null) {
                        exec.execute(task);
                        succ = true;
                    } else {
                        t.interrupt();
                        break; // make sure loop exited - flag could change again
                    }
                }       

                // Prevents 100% CPU
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                    logger.warn("Monitor thread was interrupted on wait"); // Printed on exit from JVM 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                if (e instanceof IOException 
                    && (! (e instanceof AsynchronousCloseException || e instanceof ClosedByInterruptException))
                ) reconnect = true; // reconnect only if some thread did not intendedly closed a connection     
                logger.error("Error in processing message from @" + (s != null ? s.getRemoteSocketAddress() : ""), e);
            } finally {                 
                try {
                    if (s != null && !succ) s.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error when closing socket to @" + (s != null ? s.getRemoteSocketAddress() : ""), e);
                } finally {                         
                    try {
                        if (chan != null && !succ) chan.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error("Error when closing socket channel to @" + (s != null ? s.getRemoteSocketAddress() : ""), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof IOException) reconnect = true;
        logger.error("Error in monitoring thread", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (serverSocket != null) serverSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof IOException) reconnect = true;
            logger.error("Error when closing a server socket", e);
        } finally {
            try { 
                if (ssc != null) ssc.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof IOException) reconnect = true;
                logger.error("Error when closing a server socket channel", e);
            }
        }                                       
    }

    if (t.isInterrupted()) return; // interrupted - exit
    if (!reconnect) return; // some IOExceptions can be handled by a reconnect      
    final long maxRestart = this.reconnectCounter.getAndDecrement(); // counter     
    if (maxRestart <= 0) return; // maxRestart reached - exit
    restart(maxRestart - 1); // restart this runnable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`ssocket.setReuseAddress(true);`

`socket.setReuseAddress(true);`